# javascript $.post pass parameter to external PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I have

```
enter code here

function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser is too old to run me!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    $.post('userfind.php', function(data) {


    document.getElementById("myTable").style.display = "block"; 
    var x=document.getElementById("myTable");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 

    var row=x.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(-1);
    ...
    ...
```

and in php

```
enter code here

<?php 

session_start();
$username = "XXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXX";
$database = "XXXXXXXX";
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "$username", "$password");
if(!$link) {echo("Failed to establish connection to mysql server");
         exit();}

$status = mysql_select_db($database);


$oId = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["order_IDsearch"]);


if (isset($order_IDsearch)){
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM personal_info WHERE  order_id= '".$oId."' ");
$myjsons = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
$myjsons[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($myjsons);
}

?>
```

the javascript will show the table if i remove the SQL condition, matrk if and mark $_post

and it wont show the table if i leave the php as you see above,

whats wrong with the php page help please

---

here is the whole javascript ajax function,

```
enter code here

function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser is too old to run me!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){




    $.post('userfind.php', {orderId:"order_IDsearch"}, function(data) {
    var obj = $("#myTable").show();
    var x = obj.get(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 

    var row=x.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(-1);
    ...
    ...



   cell1.innerHTML = "<b><input name='edit' type='button' onClick='editRow(this)' value='Edit' />    <input name='del' type='button' onClick='delRow(this)' value='Del' /></b>";
   cell2.innerHTML =  data[i].user_id;
   cell3.innerHTML =  data[i].first_name ;
   ....
   ....  

 }},'json');}
    }
   ajaxRequest.open("POST", "userfind.php", true);
   ajaxRequest.send(null); 
    }
```

It's so confusing me please help me to modify the code, should I write the code again? can this code be modified?

Comment: Are you using jQuery (`$.post`) or not?

Comment: @Bergi yep it's right there in the middle of the XHR state change handler :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, I've seen that - that's why I wonder :-)

Comment: @Shahab, if you're using jQuery `$.post()`, then there is no need at all for you to create an XMLHttpRequest object. The library (jQuery) will do all that for you.

Comment: @Shahab
You are not passing any value to your PHP script...
2nd paramater should be the values that you pass...

Since its empty in your code, php doesn't find anything at $_POST['order_IDsearch']

Comment: A few questions though...
You might have some specific requirement to implement it like this. But why are you using $.post nested in traditional ajax thing?

Comment: @AdityaParab yes i thought so, how to pass the argument here, arguments are texboxes from a form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not passing anything to your php file from `$.post`...

make it like

```
$.post('userfind.php', {order_IDsearch: "your data"}, function(data){
// your implementation
});
```

This should work...

If your order_IDsearch is dynamic then have it done like this

```
$.post('userfind.php', {yourData:order_IDsearch}, function(data){
    // your implementation
    });
```

And on PHP side you will have to access it in

```
$_POST['yourData'];
```

To send multiple values

```
$.post('userfind.php', {key1:value1,key2:value2,...}, function(data){
        // your implementation
        });
```

Comment: Remove quotes from parametername: `{order_IDsearch: "your data"}`

Comment: Done!
I'm just curious what difference does it make?
I am learning JSON and I have found that it just works fine even if you have or don't have those double quotes in key part

Comment: `{order_IDsearch: "your data"}` is not json , its javascript object. Quotes are optional here. But you need quotes in json.

Comment: alright! Got it... That is why we can access it like x.order_IDSearch

haha!

and thats the same reason we need to eval() the JSON string, so that we can iterate over it.. EUREKA! LOL :D

Thanks Jashwant!

Comment: well in this way only 1 argument will be bassed while i needi to submit a form with, how to pass other argument along? and one more thing, the order_IDsearch is a text box so the data is dynamic

Comment: @GeenHenk do i have quote there?

Comment: see the updated answer

PS : Remove quote comment was for me.

Comment: it yet doesn't send anything to the php file

Answer (score 3):

`Aditya Parab` really answered your question, but I must interject some jQuery basics you need to understand.

You can (and should) simplify your function DRASTICALLY. All of that `ajaxRequest` stuff, the first 20 lines or so of the code, is for use when you are NOT using jQuery Ajax. That stuff is built into jQuery and you don't have to do it.

Also, in jQuery, you can get an object by its ID by stating `var object = $('#objectId').get(0)`. You do not need `document.getElementsById()`.

---

### **Simplified Function**

---

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    $.post('userfind.php', {var1: "value 1"}, function(data) {
        var obj = $("#myTable").show();
        var x = obj.get(0); //Get the JS object from the jQuery Object
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var row=x.insertRow(-1);
            var cell1=row.insertCell(-1);
            var cell2=row.insertCell(-1);
        }
        ...
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: i did some part of your modification, bellow is what it's look like now, but still nothing

Comment: You must make the entire change. Your ajaxRequest stuff is likely mucking things up.

Comment: guys this question is for long a go, the problem has been solved already

Comment: I don't see any recent updates/additions... what's the problem?